# Looping through a string to find the first index of a particular character

Tags: string, python-2.7, indexing

```
for i in reversed(bin(n|(n+1))[2:]):#loops through representation of  
# integer n, converted to binary, and flips first 0 bit 
    if i == '0':
        print(str(count))
        count=0
        break
    count +=1
```

If n is an integer, the above sample code flips the first zero bit, then finds and prints the index of what was the second zero bit.

I'm working on CodeFights, to practice my skills and can't seem to figure out how to format an algorithm that accomplishes basically what this one does.

I'm supposed to find the appropriate index and raise 2 to that power, in one line. I'm looked into using generators and llambdas... not sure what to do.

So, specifically how can I can I get 
    2**index of second zero in integer n
    #in one line of code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def secondRightmostZeroBit(n):
    return 2**bin(n|(n+1))[::-1].index('0')
```

Researched this for days, stumbled upon the answer five minutes after asking on here. 
'.replace(0,1,1)' and
'.find(0)' would also have been useful.

The above is what I ended up submitting. As explained in the question n|(n=1), serves to flip the rightmost zero in the binary representation of n. From there I reversed the order of the string/binary representation of that result, and used '.index' to retrieve the first '0' to be found.

Another way to do it has more to do with manipulation of binary numbers than with the way I phrased the original question.

```
def secondRightmostZeroBit(n):
    return ~n & (~n-1) & -(~n & (~n-1))
```

I haven't found much reason to do this sort of bit manipulation in the past, so I'm always looking at a reference when I interpret code like this. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/bitwise_operators_example.htm   If you want to understand it, I suggest plugging in a specific number for n, convert to binary, and work it through. Do that a couple of times and it should become clear what's going on. You can also plug individual peices of it into your interactive pain, but that won't do you much good unless you're looking at the binary. bin(n) and format(n, "8b") are good for that.